# Blazor with database connection cannot delete entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app which is connected to a SQL database.
In the database I have a table "Cards" and a table "Responsibilities", which are connected to each other.
[image: database]

My cards are displayed in a tabular view where I have a "Delete" button for each card.

```
<h3>Cards</h3>

@if (cards == null)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var card in cards.Select((valueC, iC) => new { iC, valueC }))
    {
        var valueCard = card.valueC;
        var indexCard = card.iC;
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="padding" style="width:200px">@valueCard.Id @valueCard.Description</td>
                <td class="padding" style="width:250px">
                    <button type="button" style="width:100px" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => {DeleteCard(valueCard);})">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

When I delete a card that is still used in the other table I get this error:

> The association between entities 'Card' and 'Responsibility' with the
> key value '{CardId: 1}' has been severed, but the relationship is
> either marked as required or is implicitly required because the
> foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be
> deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the
> relationship to use cascade deletes.

Which makes total sense.

What I don't understand is that if I then try to delete another card that is not in use without refreshing the page, I get the same error message with the same `key value '{CardId: 1}'`.
The exception is thrown at `db.SaveChanges()`.

My Code:

```
@code
{
    dbContext db = new dbContext();

    List<Card> cards;
    public bool[] editCard;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        cards = db.Cards
            .Include(c => c.Addressee)
            .Include(c => c.Addressee.Address)
            .ToList();

        editCard = new bool[cards.Count()];
    }

    private async void DeleteCard(Card c)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Cards.Remove(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
            StateHasChanged();
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

These are the values that are passed in `DeleteCard(Card c)`:

> A filled Card

[image: Card with Responsibilities]

> A emptyCard

[image: Card without Responsibilities]

I can only imagine that it is due to `@onclick`.
But `DeleteCard(cards[indexCard]);` does not work either.
Otherwise maybe the order of the methods in `DeleteCard()` or `OnInitializedAsync()` is wrong.
If I refresh the page manually I can delete this entry without problems.

Comment: I have a similar Button for each Card, which updates the Card `db.Cards.Update(c)` and works fine

Comment: Please share the exception you mentioned.

Comment: The exception type is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904). 
But the problem is not the exception.
The problem is that I also get this message when I try to delete an empty card after trying to delete a card with a child.
I think it is because he does not take the right card

Comment: I'm no EF expert, but it seems to me you are using the same DBContext for every operation, and the first "failed save" is still held in that context. Maybe try using a new context for each operation, or at least when it errors?

Comment: That was it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The card taken from the list does not include it’s children, this may cause cascade delete to fail

```
 cards = db.Cards
        .Include(c => c.Addressee)
        .Include(c => c.Addressee.Address)
        .Include(c => c.Responsibilities)
        .ToList();
```

Update:

```
 private async void DeleteCard(Card c)
{
    try
    {
        var cardToRemove = await db.Cards
        .Include(c => c.Responsibilities)
         // include other children here…
         .FirstAsync(card => card.Id == c.Id);

        db.Cards.Remove(cardToRemove);
        db.SaveChanges();
        StateHasChanged();
        await OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Idea being to include the children in the entity to delete with the remove method. The error you get is ef core telling you that if you delete a parent the children will be orphaned (because they have a foreign key referring to the parent

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the error :/

Comment: Do you still get the same exception?

Comment: With all the children included, I still get the same exception. 

If I don't include any in the initialization and in the delete method, I get this exception: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException`: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` (0x80131904): The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_responsibility_card". The conflict occurred in database "christmas_cards", table "dbo.responsibility", column 'card_id'.

Comment: This also makes sense but I also get this message when I try to delete an empty card after trying to delete a card with a child.